# What's the difference behind normal function call and pcall

Tags: lua

I am using lua and I know pcall is for protected calling and my question is if both ways of calling all come down to the same C code. e.g.

```
function a(arg)
   ...
end
```

normal calling:

```
a(arg)
```

protected call:

```
pcall(a, arg)
```

Actually I am using 'lua_lock/lua_unlock' to protect the lua_State from corrupting. And form the source (lua 5.1.4) I can see 'lua_pcall' is calling 'lua_lock/lua_unlock', but I am not sure if normal way of function call is also based on 'lua_pcall' or using 'lua_lock/lua_unlock'? If not, does it mean that I have to change all the function calling to 'pcall(...)' to get benefit from 'lua_lock/lua_unlock'?

Could someone explain? Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`pcall` is used to handle errors in lua. I've made the following example to demonstrate how to use it:

First we make a function which me ***know*** will produce an error

```
function makeError(n)
    return 'N'+n;
end
```

Now as our first example we define the following

```
function pcallExample1()
    if pcall(makeError,n) then 
        print("no error!")
    else 
        print("That method is broken, fix it!")
    end 
end
```

We invoke `pcallExample1`

```
pcallExample1()
```

And get the output:

```
Lua 5.1.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
That method is broken, fix it!
```

To demonstrate the opposite:

```
function pcallExample2()
    if makeError(5) then 
        print("no error!")
    else 
        print("That method is broken, fix it!")
    end 
end
```

Invoking this will have the error remain unhanded and bubble up to the display:

```
lua: /Users/henryhollinworth/Desktop/s.lua:2: attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value
```

---

In terms of `C`, pcall is defined as

```
static int luaB_pcall (lua_State *L) {
  int status;
  luaL_checkany(L, 1);
  lua_pushnil(L);
  lua_insert(L, 1);  /* create space for status result */
  status = lua_pcallk(L, lua_gettop(L) - 2, LUA_MULTRET, 0, 0, pcallcont);
  return finishpcall(L, (status == LUA_OK));
}
```

Where `lua_pcallk` is

```
LUA_API int lua_pcallk (lua_State *L, int nargs, int nresults, int errfunc,
                        int ctx, lua_CFunction k) {
  struct CallS c;
  int status;
  ptrdiff_t func;
  lua_lock(L);
  api_check(L, k == NULL || !isLua(L->ci),
    "cannot use continuations inside hooks");
  api_checknelems(L, nargs+1);
  api_check(L, L->status == LUA_OK, "cannot do calls on non-normal thread");
  checkresults(L, nargs, nresults);
  if (errfunc == 0)
    func = 0;
  else {
    StkId o = index2addr(L, errfunc);
    api_checkvalidindex(L, o);
    func = savestack(L, o);
  }
  c.func = L->top - (nargs+1);  /* function to be called */
  if (k == NULL || L->nny > 0) {  /* no continuation or no yieldable? */
    c.nresults = nresults;  /* do a 'conventional' protected call */
    status = luaD_pcall(L, f_call, &c, savestack(L, c.func), func);
  }
  else {  /* prepare continuation (call is already protected by 'resume') */
    CallInfo *ci = L->ci;
    ci->u.c.k = k;  /* save continuation */
    ci->u.c.ctx = ctx;  /* save context */
    /* save information for error recovery */
    ci->u.c.extra = savestack(L, c.func);
    ci->u.c.old_allowhook = L->allowhook;
    ci->u.c.old_errfunc = L->errfunc;
    L->errfunc = func;
    /* mark that function may do error recovery */
    ci->callstatus |= CIST_YPCALL;
    luaD_call(L, c.func, nresults, 1);  /* do the call */
    ci->callstatus &= ~CIST_YPCALL;
    L->errfunc = ci->u.c.old_errfunc;
    status = LUA_OK;  /* if it is here, there were no errors */
  }
  adjustresults(L, nresults);
  lua_unlock(L);
  return status;
}
```

In contrast to `lua_callk`

```
LUA_API void lua_callk (lua_State *L, int nargs, int nresults, int ctx,
                        lua_CFunction k) {
  StkId func;
  lua_lock(L);
  api_check(L, k == NULL || !isLua(L->ci),
    "cannot use continuations inside hooks");
  api_checknelems(L, nargs+1);
  api_check(L, L->status == LUA_OK, "cannot do calls on non-normal thread");
  checkresults(L, nargs, nresults);
  func = L->top - (nargs+1);
  if (k != NULL && L->nny == 0) {  /* need to prepare continuation? */
    L->ci->u.c.k = k;  /* save continuation */
    L->ci->u.c.ctx = ctx;  /* save context */
    luaD_call(L, func, nresults, 1);  /* do the call */
  }
  else  /* no continuation or no yieldable */
    luaD_call(L, func, nresults, 0);  /* just do the call */
  adjustresults(L, nresults);
  lua_unlock(L);
}
```

Note that both make use of `lua_lock()` and `lua_unlock()`. Both lock and unlock the `lua_State`.

Comment: Note that usually - especially for development - using `xpcall` is preferable since you can actually get an error message and traceback out of it while it still does not affect the Lua runtime in case of an error.

Comment: Can we still get the original error string from this?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell yeah, `pcall` returns two values: a boolean flag that indicates if the function completed successfully, and an error string. So you use it like so: `local success, errorMessage = pcall(myFunction, parameter1, parameter2...)`. What you want is in `errorMessage`.